# Which is good and prefereble image size for layout-sw320dp

Tags: android, android-layout

320x480 is enough or should I use 480x800 for better result for layout-sw320dp. If any body have experience of this then please share.

Comment: not clear your scenario add more to your question what you want your scenario ?

Comment: I've read this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html and found that 320dp works for phone screen 240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, 720x1280xhdpi. so if I'll put 320x480 base image it will calculate for all.

Comment: sw320dp means smallest width 320 but why do you need to do that it means mdpi and you can work it out by simple layout folder

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really have to care if you are using the standard image sized for Android.

There is lot's of information on this, but in general, create your images in 4 resolutions and you should be fine.

The resolutions are (lpdi/mdpi/hdpi/xhpdi):  32/48/64/96  - which is a ratio: .5/1/1.5/2

In Eclipse, you can use the 'Asset Manager' tool (accessible from main menu - New/Other/Android/Create Icon Set

This documentation page is pretty clear: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: But as per http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html link, this is deprecated.

Comment: No way is this deprecated.  This is the proper way to use images in Android.  I think you may be reading too much into that (overcomplicated article IMHO).  Included another more clear link in my original answer).

Comment: :) that's why I've written in question > If any body have experience of this then please share.